# H.264 .f4v video 'glitch' on first playback in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flv, h.264

Can anyone familiar with H.264 video recommend the 'best' compression settings to avoid the occasional visual 'glitch' one gets on playback using the flash video player?

Comment: Do you get the same visual glitch if you change the extension to .mp4 and play it in vlc (or your choice of player)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-size-fits-all compression setting.  There are many factors, and technically, the specs defines the bitstream only, so two different coders with the "same" settings can generate different quality output.

Picking settings is part science (knowing what the settings do) and part art (knowing what settings work with what type of content).

You really need to just play with the settings and pick the output you like.

Comment: Thanks, but the visual distortion or glitches I'm seeing have really nothing to do with the quality of the rendered output. The only output I like is one without any of these 'glitches'.

The final result looks 'buggy'. I'm guessing this must be a current limitation in how the Flash Player renders H.264 video but I was hoping for a workaround.